# Kivy: Running a Clock Scheduled Function for a Specified Amount of Time

Tags: python, kivy

Trying a write a Python/Kivy program to log data on a RasPi. I have a function that runs based off the clock schedule, started and stopped by user-input. This works fine because this code needs to run infinitely as it logs data from the GPIO.

```
    def start(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.running)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.running, .1)
        
    def running(self, interval):
        
        # single_setpoint() runs GPIO code
        MainApp.single_setpoint()
        
    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.running)
```

The issue I'm running into is I now want the function which logs the data to do different things for different amounts of time. For example:

```
    def start(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.running)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.running, .1)
        
    def running(self, interval):
        
        # runs GPIO code for 10 seconds
        MainApp.10sec_setpoint()

        # runs different GPIO code for 5 seconds
        MainApp.5sec_setpoint()

        # runs more different GPIO code for 2 seconds
        MainApp.2sec_setpoint()
        
    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.running)
```

I'm at a loss for how to actually do the timing for each chunk of new code. I know I can't "sleep" for that period of time since it will block UI stuff. Since running() is a new instance every time the clock scheduler calls it, I can't persist a value to check between time.time() and time.time() + 10.

Based on looking around I *think* I need to create a second thread that kicks off a timer when running() kicks off and then check against that elapsed time, but I can't figure out how to share the elapsed time value between the two?

Comment: I don't follow, why can't you persist a value tracking when the behaviour should change?

Comment: Maybe you can (I'm very new and unfamiliar with OOP) but I haven't been able. My understanding is that each time  `Clock.schedule_interval(self.running, .1)` runs, it's a new instance of `running()`. So I'd have to pass a value back to the main program loop to keep track of the time that has elapsed. Do I have that wrong?

Comment: "new instance of running()" sounds like a misconception, `running` is a method of a class so if you keep calling the method from the same class instance then any state stored in the instance remains available. That said, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with passing variables out to a wider context either. It would probably help to have a specific runnable example to work from

Comment: I probably do have a misconception but I don't understand what I'm missing. I had a statement print the instance of `running()` on each loop. It printed a new instance on every loop as triggered by `Clock.schedule_interval`. My assumption was that the way `Clock.schedule_interval` works is new call a new instance of any method triggered by it, I'm guessing that's incorrect?